# Неправильно работает программа на Python - лишние переводы строки

Tags: python, pynput

Программа, которая логирует всё, что ты писал на клавиатуре

```
import pynput.keyboard

log = ""

def process_key_press(key):
   global log
   log = log + str(key)
   print(log)



keyboard_listener = 
pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=process_key_press)

with keyboard_listener:
   keyboard_listener.join()
```

лог должен быть слитным, а он получается в виде:

u'k'

u'i'

u'l'

u'l'

u'a'

u'l'

u'l'

Key.space

u'p'

u'y'

u't'

u'h'

u'o'

u'n'

Key.enter

Завершено

Comment: `print(log, end='')`

Comment: по умолчанию принт делает перенос строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pynput.keyboard

log = ""

def process_key_press(key):
   global log
   log = log + str(key)
   print(log.replace ("u","").replace ('Key.','').replace('spase',' ').replace ("'",''),end = '')



keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=process_key_press)

with keyboard_listener:
   keyboard_listener.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)